# Clearing phone numbers from a directory entry with the Google Admin-SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have successfully added and edited numbers to Google Apps directory entries (users) with the Admin SDK. However, I have not found a way to clear out phone entries. I have tried all of these for the body to no avail.

```
{"phones": null}
{"phones": []}
{"phones": [null]}
{"phones": [{}]}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PUT request, edit the `phones` section to the following:

`"phones": null,`

Once I did this, the phone field was removed completely. Not sure why PATCH wasn't working to update just this but PUT did the trick.

All testing was done within the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground).

More details can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_user).

Comment: That still leaves a value for phones when returned with get though. Prior to a value being set the return value was null. Now it is:

    {"phones": [{"value":"","type":"work"}]}

Normally I wouldn't care but given this, it shows an empty phone number in our directory so I would like to remove it somehow.

Comment: Hmm, I've been testing this a bit in the OAuth Playground and it doesn't seem to want to PATCH (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/performance#patch) the value to make it null with the following:

{
"phones": null
}

The PATCH returns a 200 response but the old number is still in place. Going to leave it a few to ensure it's not propagation. If not, I will need to test more.

Comment: Edited my first response as I was able to resolve this with PUT rather than PATCH.

Comment: That worked. I swear I tried that but apparently I hadn't. Thanks much!